# How to change content type for two different objectives in Spring Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-headers, httpresponse, content-type

I am working on an API that displays JSON data and downloads CSV in one single API.
The problem is how to change Content-type of my header when I intend to download CSV file ?

Below is my code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "${api.route.get.all.report}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('super_admin','owner','admin')")
public ResponseEntity<?> getReportForAll(
        @ApiParam("partnerId") @RequestParam(value = "partnerId", required = false) String partnerId,
        @ApiParam("orgId") @RequestParam(value = "orgId", required = false) String orgId,
        @ApiParam("eventId") @RequestParam(value = "eventId", required = false) String eventId,
        @ApiParam("export") @RequestParam(value = "export") boolean export,
        @ApiParam("Search Filter") @RequestBody SearchCriteriaDTO filterRequestDTO,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws WazooException, IOException {

    Object response = reportService.getReportsForAll(filterRequestDTO, partnerId, orgId, eventId, export,
            httpServletResponse);

    if (export) {
        httpServletResponse.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + response);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(waasAppUtils.createResponseEntityDTO(HttpStatusCodes.OK,
                applicationUtility.getMessage("fetched"), response));
    } else {
        httpServletResponse.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(waasAppUtils.createResponseEntityDTO(HttpStatusCodes.OK,
                applicationUtility.getMessage("fetched"), response));
    }


}
```

If the purpose is only to display data(when JSON data is populated), then its working as expected and I am getting following Headers :

```
Content-Type →application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date →Wed, 14 Mar 2018 12:27:07 GMT
Expires →0
```

Here is my response

```
{
"response_code": 200,
"response_message": null,
"response_body": [
    {
        "name": "",
        "totalCharges": {
            "platformCharge": 0.5,
            "totalCharge": 0.2,
            "basicCharge": 0.3
        },
        "id": "5a97a5930467kf42f6a2eof1"
    },
```

All good till this point. Now the problem is, when I wish to download CSV(export flag set to true), it returns simply the file name in response body :

```
{
 "response_code": 200,
 "response_message": null,
 "response_body": "/home/reports/Report_Wed Mar 14 12:26:56 UTC 2018.csv"
}
```

and the content-type is still displaying me "**application/json;charset=UTF-8**"

How can i change the content type when the flag is set to be true and display data accordingly ???

Comment: Hi, have you annotated your controller with @RestController?

Comment: Yes I have done that

Comment: You want to return just file in case of export? Or u r trying to return some  json with it?

Comment: No. just the file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return just file in case of export, try this out:

```
...

if (export) {
    return ResponseEntity
     .ok()
     .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv"))
     .header("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + fileName)
     .body(<put your file content here as byte array>);
}

...
```

Comment: But I am not having File. I am having Object. I have to serialize it ?

Comment: @Vishal, but how can it be that you dont have the file? You r saying that you want to download CSV... Means that you should have the file, in memory at least

Comment: Object response = reportService.getReportsForAll(filterRequestDTO, partnerId, orgId, eventId, export,
            httpServletResponse);

As you can see from the code, I have the object. And yes I have file contents henceforth

Comment: @Vishal, but what is it for? as far as I understand, in case of export - its a String with file path in it?... If so - you can just take the file by this pass and write it to response

Comment: @Lefffchik : Buddy, if the export flag is set to false then I am returning an arraylist. If false, it is a file. So, I have kept the return type to Object. Please correct me if my approach is wrong